# How can I remove Ruby, Rails & mysql to start the installation process again?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to get setup with Ruby on Rails today, but I think I've followed some bad instructions along the way, and nothing seems to work. I've now borrowed the book "Agile Web Development with Rails, Third Edition" from a friend, and want to follow the setup instructions in that. Firstly, do I need to remove what I've setup previously? If yes, how do I do it? I can't seem to find instructions anywhere.
I'm running OSX 10.6.1, so I know that it came with some stuff already setup, but I've been installing customized stuff over the top which I think I'll have to remove. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Format? what are you talking! that should be the last option.

Comment: Do you remember what "stuff" did you install yourself?

Comment: What are those "bad instructions along the way"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To uninstall gem you can use command line :

`gem uninstall rails`

You can list all of your gem with `gem list` and delete it all.

With MacOS, I recommend using rvm (http://rvm.beginrescue.com). It's a really great tool. To isolate yours rubies and yours gems. If you install rvm and want delete all your stuff, just `rm -rf ~/.rvm` is needed.

In your Home directory by default all gem are in directory `~/.gem/`